# xCode / iOS - Help needed making a core data search predicate work

Tags: xcode, core-data, ios5, uisearchbar

I've been working on this problem for so long, I've missed the entire football season and not seen my beloved Redskins lose almost all their games again. Even my beloved Arsenal are not doing well without my support, so please help:

I am iterating through a series of core data objects. I'm trying to find objects where the main and sub-entities contain a search term. If they do, I want to add them to a results array.

There are hundreds of lines of junk code now are wasted and will never be used because the different threads I've followed and false leads taken..

The code so far is this:

```
NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);

NSMutableArray *tempArray = [NSMutableArray array];

for (NSManagedObject *object in tableViewModel.items) {
    //myPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(people.name contains[cd] %@)", searchText];
    //another one for the junk heap

    NSLog(@"searchText: %@", searchText); //this is ok
    NSLog(@"\n\nobject is: %@\n\n", object); //this is ok

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(people.name contains[cd] %@)", searchText];

    BOOL ok = [predicate evaluateWithObject:object]; // this is not ok
    if (ok) {
        NSLog (@"result is TRUE");
        [tempArray addObject:object];
        NSLog(@"\n\ntempArray: %@\n\n", tempArray);
    } else {
        NSLog (@"result is FALSE");
    }
}

NSLog(@"out of records");
autoSearchResults = tempArray;
NSLog(@"\n\nautoSearchResults: %@\n\n", autoSearchResults);

return autoSearchResults; // return my own search array
```

What I get as output is as follows:

```
object is: <MainEntity: 0x79c51cb0> (entity: MainEntity; id: 0x79c50880 <x-coredata://99B12EAD-002C-402C-99CA-CF5A328E67E5/MainEntity/p2> ; data: {
    audioName = 00010206120609;
    audioNo = 0;
    date = "2012-02-06 11:10:00 +0000";
    Main = "Main-0001 12.02.06";
    interpret = nil;
    keyword = "<relationship fault: 0x79c708a0 'keyword'>";
    order = 0;
    people = "<relationship fault: 0x79c708c0 'people'>";
    place = "<relationship fault: 0x79c710b0 'place'>";
    recurring = 0;
    summary = Test1;
    symbol = "<relationship fault: 0x79c71110 'symbol'>";
    type = "<relationship fault: 0x79c71170 'type'>";
})

2012-02-06 10:00:11.454 Appkeeper[42598:16c03] result is FALSE
```

I don't know if I need to use a predicate, whether the predicate is correct. I do not think that I'm testing the condition correctly.

So any help will be greatly appreciated..

EDIT - Adding a bit of the relationship model....

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
for (NSManagedObject *object in tableViewModel.items) {
   for (NSManagedObject *person in object.people) {
      if (person.name && 
          [person.name rangeOfString:searchTerm 
                             options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch]) {
         NSLog(@"%@ contains %@.", person.name, searchTerm);
      }
      else {
         NSLog(@"%@ does not contain %@.", person.name, searchTerm);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mundi.. No joy.. I cannot get the "object.people" to resolve: "Property people not found on object of type NSManagedObject".. But I can get hold of a string value (str1), so if there was some kind of comparison I could use, like "str1 contains searchTerm", that would be great.

Comment: Great. Your error message explains exactly what's wrong. Your data model is not set up correctly. Check your xcdatamodeld and make sure that you have a to-many relationship named `people` between your main entity and the other entity of which you want to check the value of the property `name`.

Comment: I do.. I'll add the relationship table to my original question... I really appreciate the help..

Comment: OK. You need to cast the NSManagedObject to whatever class your entities are. E.g. in the second for loop: `for (PeopleEntity *person in object.people)`, assuming you have also cast `object` accordingly.

Comment: some progress :)... I can now find objects with if they only have one name. If there are two or more, the search cannot find them. any ideas?  Thanks again!

Comment: I thought `name` is a property of PeopleEntity. Sure there will be only one.